# Combining HTML onclick functions from two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a choose your own adventure game, and I currently have two buttons on the page: one that passes variables from HTML to JavaScript, and one that calls the JavaScript function to start the game. They both work fine on their own, but I want to merge them into one button that performs both functions. Here's the code:

```
  <button onclick="add(document.getElementById('FirstName').value, document.getElementById('LastName').value)">Add</button>

   <button onclick="pirates();"> Ready to Play? </button>
```

Comment: `add(...); pirates();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add `add(document.getElementById('FirstName').value, document.getElementById('LastName').value)` To the beginning of your `pirates()` function, then clicking the 'Ready to Play?' button would do both things.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  function pirates(){
    add(
      document.getElementById('FirstName').value,
      document.getElementById('LastName').value
    )
  }
</script>
<button onclick="pirates();"> Ready to Play? </button>
```

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks so so much :D

Comment: No worries. Please mark it as an answer to prevent userside stack overflows ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add the id `btn` to your button, this script will get the values and pass them to `pirates()`.

```
var firstName;
var lastName

btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  firstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
  lastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
  pirates(firstName, lastName);
};
```